# Does react make it unnecessary to clean up view objects?

Tags: backbone.js, reactjs

Different sources suggest that unbinding events in react becomes a no-brainer. Is it true? In Backbone it is not unusual to have an instance function just for cleanup.

So when migrating to react, it is not necessary anymore to have `close` functions attached to views, in order to prevent memory leakage and other ugly effects?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you write something like

```
var Test = React.createClass({
    handleClick: function() { ... },
    render: function() {
        return <div onClick={this.handleClick}>...</div>;
    }
});
```

then React will clean up the event handlers when you unmount Test (whether you call `React.unmountComponentAtNode` or have the parent not render it).

If you add other event in componentDidMount, you should clean them up in componentWillUnmount to prevent leaks.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Just one followup: can this be generalized to all bindings (implictly) defined in the HTML template within `render()`? For example something like `return <div>{this.model.get('email')}</div>;`?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly which bindings you're referring to, but code like that would not need any special cleanup code.

Comment: You're right, it's no formal binding. Eventhough in frameworks like Backbone one would usually create an onchange listener that makes the GC not collect the garbage...